# XCRC command causes 550-reply

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, ftp, configuration-files

I'm using ProFTPd and trying to make an upload-only account

Everything is working correctly exxept that after the file is uploaded a XCRC-command is sent to check that everything went well.

That XCRC command is getting a 550 reply.

My question is:

What command FTP-command (raw) is needed for XCRC to work properly.

Contents of the `<Directory>` in the conf

```
GroupOwner www-data 
UserOwner www-data 
<Limit ALL> 
    DenyUser videouploader 
</Limit> 
<Limit STOR CWD MKD XCRC CRC LIST> 
    AllowAll 
</Limit>
```

Also a sidequestion, the GroupOwner/UserOwner is not working properly anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by approaching from the other direction, allowing all commands then denying most of the commands.

```
<Limit DELE NLST RETR RMD RNFR RNTO SITE SYST SITE_CHMOD SITE_CHGRP SITE_MKDIR SITE_RMDIR SITE_SYMLINK SITE_UTIME LIST>
        DenyUser videouploader
</Limit>
```

Not the most pretty solution, but it works.